# error in: cross compiling and linking with Android NDK r25c clang++

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am writing a cross compiled C++ project on Linux 64 bit (`x86_64`) as host machine and `Android ArmV7-a 32 bit` as target machine. In `Android NDK r25c`, everything has to be compiled with clang++. The separate cpp files compilation works but the final linkage to make the end executable file, is rejected by clang++.

To be more specific, these are in my makefile:

```
CC = clang++
TARGET = --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33
CPP_VERSION = -std=c++17

$(CC) $(TARGET) -Iinclude -c Client.cpp -o ../bin/Client.o $(CPP_VERSION)
$(CC) $(TARGET) -Iinclude -c Server.cpp -o ../bin/Server.o $(CPP_VERSION)
$(CC) $(TARGET) -Iinclude -c client_main.cpp -o ../bin/client_main.o $(CPP_VERSION)
$(CC) $(TARGET) -Iinclude -c server_main.cpp -o ../bin/server_main.o $(CPP_VERSION)

$(CC) $(TARGET) -o ../bin/cmain.out ../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o
$(CC) $(TARGET) -o ../bin/smain.out ../bin/Server.o ../bin/server_main.o
```

and this is the output:

```
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c Client.cpp -o ../bin/Client.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c Server.cpp -o ../bin/Server.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c client_main.cpp -o ../bin/client_main.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c server_main.cpp -o ../bin/server_main.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -o ../bin/cmain.out ../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o
clang-14: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Exec format error
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and the `verbose` version of the same output gives:

```
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c Client.cpp -o ../bin/Client.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c Server.cpp -o ../bin/Server.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c client_main.cpp -o ../bin/client_main.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -Iinclude -c server_main.cpp -o ../bin/server_main.o -std=c++17
clang++ --target=armv7a-linux-androideabi33 -o ../bin/cmain.out ../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o
clang-14: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Exec format error
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Android (9352603, based on r450784d1) clang version 14.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0cca074e9238af8b4106c30add4418f6)

Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-android33
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: xxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin

"xxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/ld" -pie -EL --warn-shared-textrel -z now -z relro -z max-page-size=4096 -X --hash-style=gnu --enable-new-dtags --eh-frame-hdr -m armelf_linux_eabi -dynamic-linker 

/system/bin/linker -o ../bin/cmain.out xxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/33/crtbegin_dynamic.o -Lxxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.7/lib/linux/arm -Lxxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/33 

-Lxxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi -Lxxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/../lib -Lxxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib 

../bin/Client.o ../bin/client_main.o xxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.7/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-arm-android.a -l:libunwind.a -ldl -lc xxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.7/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-arm-android.a -l:libunwind.a 

-ldl xxx/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/33/crtend_android.o
```

what can I do to compile and link the final executable file for the specified target hardware?

**Note:** The same source code has been successfully compiled, linked, and tested on the host machine with both `G++` and `clang++` compilers.